# Cognito Forms: French version missing required field alerts

Tags: cognito-forms

The French version apparently does not show the red alert message when the user does not fill in a field as required. Has anyone noticed this and/or have a solution?

Answer (score 1):

The validation message for required fields should be appearing just fine in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) for all supported languages.  For example, here is a new French form with a required field showing what happens when clicking Submit:

[image]

If you are have a problem with a specific form, please submit a support request and we will be glad to help!

Comment: Hi Jamie
This is exactly the kind of message that does not appear with my french forms. It works well in Dutch but when i copy the Dutch form to create a french version (and switch to this language), the error messages doest not appear anymore.

Comment: After follow-up with @FrançoisLambert, we determined that a French translation was missing for a specific text length validation condition and are fixing it!